# Maintaining scale factor for essential matrix

Tags: computer-vision, matlab, opencv, monocular

I want to recover the trajectory of a vehicle using a monocular camera via the computation of the essential matrix between `t-1` and `t`.
When I used OpenCV, I got correct trajectory wrt the ground truth. However, I want to code all the functions in Matlab but I got garbage when I plotted the trajectory and I think it is related to a scale factor problem.

In fact, the outputted essential matrix from opencv function is the following (between two consecutive frames)

$$ E = \begin{bmatrix}
 0.0052 & -0.7068 &  0.0104\\
 0.0052 & -0.7068 &  0.0104\\
 0.7063 &  0.0050 & -0.0305\\
-0.0113 &  0.0168 &  0.0002\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

After decomposing it into Rotation and translation and triangulating for 5 2D points, I got the following 3D points:

$$   X1 =\begin{bmatrix}
       -0.0940& 0.0478& -0.4984\\
       -0.0963& 0.0497& -0.4987\\
        0.3033& 0.1009& -0.5202\\
       -0.0065& 0.0636& -0.5053\\
       -0.0737& 0.0653& -0.5011\\
 \end{bmatrix}$$

Now, for the essential matrix outputted by Matlab functions, it is the following:

$$   E2=\begin{bmatrix}
       -0.2153 & 0.9573 & 0.1626\\
        0.8948 & 0.2456 &-0.3474\\
        0.1003 & 0.1348 &-0.0306\\
 \end{bmatrix}$$

When decomposing it into rotation and translation as well, and triangulating points, I got the following 3D points:

$$  X2 =\begin{bmatrix}
        0.1087&   -0.0552&    0.5762\\
        0.1129&   -0.0578&    0.5836\\
        0.4782&    0.1582&   -0.8198\\
        0.0028&   -0.0264&    0.2099\\
        0.0716&   -0.0633&    0.4862\\
 \end{bmatrix}$$

To verify the results, I did:

$$ X1./X2 =\begin{bmatrix}
       -0.8644 &   -0.8667 &   -0.8650\\
       -0.8524 &   -0.8603 &   -0.8546\\
        0.6343 &    0.6376 &    0.6346\\
       -2.3703 &   -2.4065 &   -2.4073\\
       -1.0288 &   -1.0320 &   -1.0305\\
 \end{bmatrix}$$

And an almost constant scale factor seems to exist between the first and second estimations. 
I think that the scale factor have to be the same for all 3D points to get a correct trajectory when plotting it. How to maintain the scale factor?